# How do I force jade to re-render template to .html when a linked .css file changes w/ livereload and Grunt?

Tags: css, express, gruntjs, pug, livereload

I'm trying to configure Grunt so that whenever a linked .css file changes, the jade template which references the .css also livereloads.  I cannot compile my jade templates, as far as I know, because the template in question is formatting a response from an API.  So, unless there is a change to the .jade file, the .css is not pulled in again.  I can manually refresh the page to view the style change, but I'm trying to automate it.

Right now, if I change a .jade file, the .jade file in question livereloads and I can see the template changes in my browser immediately.  If I change a .css file, grunt detects it and reloads the .css file.  However, since the .jade file has already been rendered into .html, the styling does not update.

EDIT: I've since determined that ONLY Jade files which include formatting API call data are affected.  Jade files that are formatting static data update with Livereload correctly upon changing .css files.

Below find my Gruntfile.js and the Jade template I am using.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({
    concat: {
        dist: {
            src: ['main.js']
        }
    },
    watch: {
        options: {
            livereload:true
        },
        css: {
            files: ['public/css/*.css'],
            options: {
            }
        },
        js: {
            files: ['routes/**/*.js', 'main.js', 'Gruntfile.js'],
            options: {
            }
        },
        jade: {
            files: ['views/**/*.jade'],
            options: {
                spawn: true
            }
        }
    },
    express: {
        dev: {
          options: {
              script: 'main.js'
          }
        }
    }
});

grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-express-server');
grunt.registerTask('server',['express', 'watch']);
grunt.registerTask('default', ['server']);

};
```

The Jade Template:

```
    doctype html
    html(lang="en")
        head
            link(rel='stylesheet', href='http://localhost:9000/css/search.css')
            link(rel='stylesheet', href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto')

    title= pageTitle

    body

    h1 Here are your results!

    ul.products
        each item, index in items
            li
                a(href=item.viewItemURL)
                    img(src=item.galleryURL)
                    p=item.title
                    -var currentPrice = Number(item.sellingStatus[0].currentPrice[0].__value__);
                    p.price $#{currentPrice.toFixed(2)}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting css paths in jade

```
watch: {
    ...
    jade: {
        files: ['views/**/*.jade', 'public/css/*.css'],
        options: {
            spawn: true
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Just as an FYI, as I've been down the road creating an array already, putting both paths into the same array still only triggers the update of the specific file which changed.